# how to exclude model form validation from admin

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need if a user does not select the field `acc_type`, the user will not proceed to registration. So I have written in model `blank=False`. But the problem is when `superuser` updates his information after login, user form holds `superuser` to fill that field. So, I want validation for some fields should be excluded for `superuser`, `stuff` or admin type users. Please see the screenshot: [image]

What I did in model:

**models.py**

```
class Ext_User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    ACC_TYPE = (
        (1, "Member"),
        (2, "Vendor")
    )
    acc_type = models.IntegerField("Account Type", choices=ACC_TYPE, null=True, blank=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way 'round - what you want here is to allow blank in the model and override the ModelForm used in your public view (not the admin one) to forbid it:

models:

```
class Ext_User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    ACC_TYPE = (
        (1, "Member"),
        (2, "Vendor")
    )
    # Allow blank for the django admin
    acc_type = models.IntegerField("Account Type", choices=ACC_TYPE, null=True, blank=True)
```

public view's form:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ext_user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # make the field required for the public form
        self.fields["acc_type"].required = True
```

Another solution is to add a dedicated "admin" ACC_TYPE choice, and remove it from the public ModelForm's choices so end users only have the "member" and "vendor" choices left:

models:

```
class Ext_User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    ACC_TYPE = (
        (0, "Admin"), # add an 'Admin' choice for the django admin
        (1, "Member"),
        (2, "Vendor")
    )
    acc_type = models.IntegerField("Account Type", choices=ACC_TYPE, null=True, blank=False)
```

public view's form:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ext_user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # exclude the 'admin' choice for the public form
        self.fields["acc_type"].choices = Ext_user.ACC_TYPES[1:]
```

Comment: actually, I am new at django. can you give me a little bit more idea then it would help me?

Comment: @StreetCoder I edited my post to add code examples. Those are untested, but based on existing working code so they should JustWork(tm).